# Why is it caused by overlapping outputs?

Tags: javascript

I want to make input box
um..

I started JS this week.. why it fires twice? plz help me :)..

if I press 1 , 2 , 3 , Just log will be 1, 2, 3..

```js
const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form')
const myArea = document.querySelector('#text-A')

myArea.addEventListener('keydown', function(a) {

  myForm.addEventListener('input', function(a) {
    console.log(a.currentTarget)
  })

  if (a.which == 13) {
    if (!a.shiftKey) {
      a.preventDefault();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
  <script defer src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="my-form">
    <textarea type="submit" id="text-A" name="text-A"> </textarea>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Both `keydown` and `input` will fire, when you type a new character into the textbox. And every time keydown fires, you are adding an _additional_ input event handler.

Comment: I wanna do ..
I want to write down text in textarea  when When I press enter I wanna that value
So just trying to get value by input event !
and I used keypress because I want to use enter to send, and enter + shift to change the line

Answer (score 0):

Do not nest your addEventListeners and do not call addEventListener in an event that can repeat, for example when clicking a button.

`textarea type="submit"` is also incorrect. You can have
`<input type="submit"`, `<button type="submit"` and <input type="image" which is also a submit, but not `<textarea type="submit"`

Here is how to submit a form when pressing enter but not shift-enter in a form with only one field

```js
const myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form')
const myArea = document.querySelector('#text-A')

myArea.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) { // we use e for event
  if (e.key === 'Enter' // we can use better names when using event.key
    && !e.shiftKey) myArea.form.submit(); // submit if enter but not shift-enter
})
myForm.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.id)
})
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <textarea id="text-A" name="text-A"></textarea>
</form>
```